# Can Skeleton Killed Creepers Be Autospawned

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

As we all know, when a skeleton kills a creeper it drops an music disk, and if you didn't know you can pick up an mob during its dying animation using a safari net and auto spawn exact copies of it which will instantly die. When you make a skeleton kill a creeper, and you can catch it before it dies, can you put it through the autospawner and autospawn creepers that will drop music disks?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: You can't catch dying entities.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would be any more difficult to just make a normal record farm, aside from needing to be there for the skeleton to shoot. Also, creepers *always* drop music disks when killed by a skeleton, fyi.

Comment: I did write it always dropped, someone else edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the record would not drop. The arrow does not maintain the shooter as a nbt tag and the creeper does not maintain the killer as a NBT tag either.

When capturing a mob in a safari net, it saves all of the NBT information of the creature, and because the creeper does not store the DamageSource in a NBT tag, this information is lost upon capturing a creature.